# Gold, Silver and Bronze ages for DC comics

Tags: dc, comics, history-of

Surfing the Internet on Superman, you often come across the three "ages": The Golden Age, the Silver Age and the Bronze Age. Who originally came up with these ages and what were the reasons given for the choices?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Comic_Books / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Age_of_Comic_Books / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_Age_of_Comic_Books / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Age_of_Comic_Books

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research effort. A nano-second of googling has highlighted a dozen highly authoritative sources that answer this exact question.

Comment: @Valorum still, it a be a good idea to have an answer _here_.

Comment: @SQB - I stand ready to upvote a decently put together answer.

Answer (score 10):

**The Golden Age** - the starting point of the Golden Age is fairly strongly established as running from the 1938 publication of *Action Comics* #1 (starring Superman; cover-dated June 1938). The end is a bit fuzzier. Super-heroes were popular (but not exclusively so) throughout the World War II era. After the war, the popularity of super-heroes waned; by the early 1950's, Superman, Batman, and Wonder Woman were the only DC super-heroes who still had self-titled comics on the newsstands by 1951 (and the only super-heroes who had their own titles through the whole period between the Golden and Silver Ages), and that's about when the Golden Age is considered as having ended.

**The Silver Age** - This age also has a generally accepted starting point tied to the publication of a specific comic book - DC's *Showcase* #4 (cover date Sept - Oct 1956) featuring a revamped version of a Golden Age character, the Flash. There are stories before that point that logically fit in the Silver Age from a continuity perspective (the Martian Manhunter, a founding member of the Justice League, debuted about a year before), but that's really the starting point. The revival of the Flash went well enough to lead to other characters being revamped and reintroduced at DC - Green Lantern, the Atom, Hawkman - and, of course, the revamping of the golden age Justice Society from *All-Star Comics* as the Justice League. Which, famously, lead Martin Goodman to ask Stan Lee to come up with his own "Justice League" - leading to the publication of *Fantastic Four* #1.

Again, the end of the Silver Age is fuzzier. A cut-off point in 1970 generally seems to make sense. Jack Kirby's move from Marvel to DC, Denny O'Neil and Neal Adams' run on *Green Lantern/Green Arrow*, Marvel's publication of *Conan the Barbarian* #1, and the death of Gwen Stacy in *Amazing Spider-man* #122 have all been considered as possible end points (though I agree that the Spider-Man issue, published in 1973, seems a bit late).

**The Bronze Age** - Unlike the Golden and Silver ages, no "gap period" between the end of the Silver Age and the start of the Bronze Age exists; the latter picks up wherever the former left off. Thus, the relatively fuzziness of the end of the Silver Age leaves us with a fuzzy start to the Bronze Age, probably around 1970.

The Bronze Age also lacks the clear definition in terms of what it was, by comparison to the previous two ages. The Golden Age was the marked by the birth of the super-hero in comics; the Silver Age, by the super-hero's return to prominence. In the 1970s and 1980s, super-hero comics maintained their position, for the most part. The "Bronze Age" may have reflected an increased push towards touching injustice and inequality in the real world - but that probably had as much to do with a new generation of comics creators taking over the comics themselves. The Bronze Age pretty much saw the death of non-Marvel, non-DC newsstand comics, and the birth of the direct market.

The end of the Bronze Age is even fuzzier than its start, but is generally considered to be around 1985-1986. At DC, this was when *Crisis on Infinite Earths* eliminated Earth-I and Earth-II (and a slew of others), and many characters (including Superman and Wonder Woman) being rebooted with altered back stories. At Marvel, this is about when *Marvel Super-Hero Secret Wars* was published, and marks the end of several titles started early in the Bronze Age, like *Luke Cage, Hero for Hire* (later *Power Man*, then *Power Man/Iron Fist*) and *The Defenders*.

**The naming of the "Ages"**

The terms golden age, silver age, and bronze age significantly predate comics - they can be found in [Greek and Roman literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_Man) from more than 2000 years ago. The terms have been applied to a vast number of things over the centuries. In the 20th century, the term was applied to two potentially relevant things: the golden age of Hollywood, and the golden age of science fiction.

Fandom applied those terms to comics over the years - there's a "first recorded" reference for the Golden Age, and a partial reference for Silver.

- The first recorded use of the term "Golden Age" was by Richard A. Lupoff in an article, "Re-Birth", published in issue one of Fanzine's Comic Art in April 1960. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Comic_Books)).
- Comics historian and movie producer Michael Uslan traces the origin of the "Silver Age" term in comics to the letters column of *Justice League of America* #42 (Feb. 1966), which went on sale December 9, 1965. Letter-writer Scott Taylor of Westport, Connecticut wrote, "If you guys keep bringing back the heroes from the 1930s-1940s Golden Age, people 20 years from now will be calling this decade the Silver Sixties!" From here, the concept of Gold and Silver Ages as a natural progression (with Bronze as the logical next age) took hold in the fan community. Not long after this, dealers selling old comics took up the convention when listing items for sale. And, it's been with us ever since. (Again, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Age_of_Comic_Books)).
- The name of the Bronze Age was in place before it even started, as noted above.
- A number of names have been suggested for the era(s) following the "Bronze Age":

  - Perhaps most notable is the "Dark Age", as post-Bronze Age was when comics seemed to become notably darker in tone, on the one hand with characters like the Punisher and Wolverine becoming prominent, and on the other with stories like *Watchmen* and *The Dark Knight Returns* appearing, leading to DC's Vertigo comics line.
  - Another popular term for a time was the "Chromium Age", referring to the various special covers many comics were given to attract attention and sales in the 90s: chromium covers, die-cut covers, variant art covers, variant story comics (DC's *Team Titans* 1 had five separate versions, each with it's own cover highlighting one member of the team, with the same main story, but a different "backup" story featuring that character); comics in poly bags with trading cards, posters, and other paraphernalia; and so on.
  - The source material would suggest the Iron Age as the next logical step. However, fandom has never bought into that as they did the previous three names.

Comment: As a rule, ages and periods of history get their names after they are over. They are recognized by particular historic events or societal changes that are more easily identified with the gift of hindsight. There's many comics historians that would carry the Silver Age right up to Crisis on Infinite Earths - that book is certainly the point of change between two ages, which they are is up for debate.

Comment: @VBartilucci - No argument here. The changes in the early- to mid-80s (*Crisis*, mini-series, Marvel and DC starting to publish direct-market-only books (*Moon Knight*, *Ka-Zar*, *Micronauts*; and the DC "hardbacks" *New Teen Titans*, *Legion*, and *Outsiders*)) seem more important that the changes around 1970, involving movement by creators, and a new generation of creators coming in. A new age starting immediately after the previous one seems off, too. However, I covered the terms as they seem to be in general use today (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Very interesting. As for Superman, the bronze age seems to have been when kryptonite disappeared and he lost a lot of his power to the creature known as Quarmer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman_Saga

As for Marvel (even if this topic is about DC), it ended around Secret Wars. Based on my own opinion; for Hulk it ended with issue 292. For Spider-Man about the time he got his black suit. When Byrne left X-Men, that was definetely the end of an era, even if it kept selling good. Also when Byrne took over Fantastic Four it was both the end and the beginning of an era.